# Unable to import PasswordEncoderUtils

Tags: spring, spring-security

`spring-security-core-4.2.3.RELEASE` has a class `org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.PasswordEncoderUtils`

[image]

But when I try to import it in my application it is unavailable. Also it does not show up in the official documentation for this package.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/encoding/package-summary.html

But I know it lives in my application because inspecting the source of other spring security classes I can see it in use and even inspect the source for the class itself.

Comment: It's not a public class. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @holmis83 how is it not a public class? I am able to view the source file for it, it is not an inner/nested class. I am trying to use it for the matching passwords functionality it provides

Comment: Did you succeed to import it ? I'am facing the same issue